# Haskell Regex performance

Tags: regex, performance, haskell

I've been looking at the existing options for regex in Haskell, and I wanted to understand where the gap in performance came from when comparing the various options with each other and especially with a simple call to grep...

I have a relatively small (~ 110M, compared to a usual several 10s of G in most of my use cases) trace file :

```sh
$ du radixtracefile
113120 radixtracefile
$ wc -l radixtracefile
1051565 radixtracefile
```

---

- I first tried to find how many matches of the (arbitrary) pattern `.*504.*ll` were in there through grep :

```sh
$ time grep -nE ".*504.*ll" radixtracefile | wc -l
309

real   0m0.211s
user   0m0.202s
sys    0m0.010s
```

---

- I looked at Text.Regex.TDFA (version 1.2.1) with Data.ByteString :

```hs
import Control.Monad.Loops
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
    f <- B.readFile "radixtracefile"
    matches :: [[B.ByteString]] <- f =~~ ".*504.*ll"
    mapM_ (putStrLn . show . head) matches
```

Building and running :

```sh
$ ghc -O2 test-TDFA.hs -XScopedTypeVariables
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test-TDFA.hs, test-TDFA.o )
Linking test-TDFA ...
$ time ./test-TDFA | wc -l
309

real   0m4.463s
user   0m4.431s
sys    0m0.036s
```

---

- Then, I looked at Data.Text.ICU.Regex (version 0.7.0.1) with Unicode support:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Loops
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Data.Text.ICU.Regex

main = do
    re <- regex [] $ T.pack ".*504.*ll"
    f <- TIO.readFile "radixtracefile"
    setText re f
    whileM_ (findNext re) $ do
        a <- start re 0
        putStrLn $ "last match at :"++(show a)
```

Building and running :

```sh
$ ghc -O2 test-ICU.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test-ICU.hs, test-ICU.o )
Linking test-ICU ...
$ time ./test-ICU | wc -l
309

real   1m36.407s
user   1m36.090s
sys    0m0.169s
```

---

I use ghc version 7.6.3. I haven't had the occasion of testing other Haskell regex options. I knew that I would not get the performance that I had with grep and was more than happy with that, but more or less 20 times slower for the TDFA and ByteString... That is very scary. And I can't really understand why it is what it is, as I naively though that this was a wrapper on a native backend... Am I somehow not using the module correctly ?

(And let's not mention the ICU + Text combo which is going through the roof)

Is there an option that I haven't tested yet that would make me happier ?

**EDIT** :

- Text.Regex.PCRE (version 0.94.4) with Data.ByteString :

```hs
import Control.Monad.Loops
import Data.Maybe
import Text.Regex.PCRE
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
    f <- B.readFile "radixtracefile"
    matches :: [[B.ByteString]] <- f =~~ ".*504.*ll"
    mapM_ (putStrLn . show . head) matches
```

Building and running :

```sh
$ ghc -O2 test-PCRE.hs -XScopedTypeVariables
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test-PCRE.hs, test-PCRE.o )
Linking test-PCRE ...
$ time ./test-PCRE | wc -l
309

real   0m1.442s
user   0m1.412s
sys    0m0.031s
```

Better, but still with a factor of ~7-ish ...

Comment: What exact Haskell implementation are you talking about? That could make quite a difference.

Comment: @vonbrand: The snippets mention `ghc -O2`. Does the (compiler/library) version matter, or what do you want to know?

Comment: @vonbrand: `$ ghc --version` gives `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3`. `cabal list regex-tdfa` gives (among other things) `regex-tdfa [...] Installed versions: 1.2.1`, and `cabal list text-icu`, `text-icu [...] Installed versions: 0.7.0.1`. Was that the information you were looking for ? I will edit my question to add this information.

Comment: Without knowing the details: do the `regex-*` implementations parse line-wise (as `grep`), or document-wise? That can make a __huge__ difference. Also, if you can provide a way to reconstruct `radixtracefile`, one could investigate this problem locally.

Comment: @Zeta: in the ByteString case, all I provide is one big ByteString that has all the '\n' in there. I am not sure what Text does but it may do the line breaking thing... I have also tried a version where I first split my ByteString on each '\n' and then run the regex on each individual one and that performs somewhere in between the two example I gave (real 0m42.767s
user 0m42.506s
sys 0m0.264s).

Comment: @zakyggaps Thanks, I am actually using the Lazy ByteString in my actual program (not the tiny ones I've posted here), so I am aware of that observation, but I didn't know about `conduit` and will probably get down to looking into it. However, I am not quite sure I understand how it would change the performance of the various regex modules... ?

Comment: @Zeta Since the content of the file probably doesn't matter much, you can use something like `dd if=/dev/urandom of=radixtracefile bs=1M count=100` to make a 100M file. It was enough for me to reproduce gameboo's timings, roughly (and learn that switching to lazy bytestrings doesn't really change much).

Comment: @zakyggaps I wanted to give conduit (did a bit of reading), sounds pretty cool. I can certainly see how it would help with memory consumption (and I'm definitely giving that a go). I am still unclear on how it could help the tdfa library to work faster... Which also leads me to a side question : did you have a small example of the program I posted only rewritten with the streaming io style ? Is it even possible to still interface with the tdfa library that expects a ByteString rather than individual elements of the stream ? (not sure how to wrap the call to `=~` in a `Conduit` there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after looking at other libraries for a bit, I ended up trying PCRE.Ligth (version 0.4.0.4) :

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Text.Regex.PCRE.Light
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

main = do
    f <- B.readFile "radixtracefile"
    let lines = B.split '\n' f
    let re = compile (B.pack ".*504.*ll") []
    forM_ lines $ \l -> maybe (return ()) print $ match re l []
```

Here is what I get out of that :

```sh
$ ghc -O2 test-PCRELight.hs -XScopedTypeVariables
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test-PCRELight.hs, test-PCRELight.o )
Linking test-PCRELight ...
$ time ./test-PCRELight | wc -l
309

real   0m0.832s
user   0m0.803s
sys    0m0.027s
```

I think this is decent enough for my purposes. I might try to see what happens with the other libs when I manually do the line splitting like I did here, although I doubt it's going to make a big difference.